# Do we need to install WIF framework on Relying Party application or just using WIF dll in application would work?

Tags: c#, wif, adfs2.0

Do we need to install WIF framework on Relying Party application or just using WIF dll in application would work?

I am using VSTS 2010 and WIF 3.5 dll, but i am not sure whether do we need to install wif 3.5 framework when wanted to setup other machines as RP.

and also can i use WIF 4.0 instead of WIF 3.5?

Comment: Consider upgrading to .NET 4.5 where WIF is a part of the framework. From what I remeber, you DO need the WIF runtime installed.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Zychla, but upgrading 4.5 is not possible, but i think as per this article only web config and dll is required. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638734.aspx , Can you please verify and confirm again?

Comment: I think we only need framework when we want that Add STS Reference or other Federation related functinality in visual studio, Am i correct? and not really to setup application ?

Comment: We've been using WIF for ages and we were always installing the runtime on application servers. Now, as all our applications are upgraded to .net 4.5, I can't verify it anymore. But definitely, WIF 3.5 was for vs2008, WIF 4.0 was for vs2010.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use WIF 3.5 in VS 2010, there are two steps you will need to take:

1- Install WIF Runtime from here: [Windows Identity Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331)

2- Install WIF SDK for .NET Framework 4.0 from here: [Windows Identity Foundation SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451)

Reference:

[Create claims aware Wcf Service using WIF on Framework 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/05/13/create-claims-aware-wcf-service-using-wif-on-framework-4-0.aspx)